# How to control learning rate in KerasR in R

Tags: r, neural-network, keras-rl

To fit a classification model in R, have been using `library(KerasR)`. To control learning rate and [KerasR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kerasR/kerasR.pdf) says

```
compile(optimizer=Adam(lr = 0.001, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999, epsilon = 1e-08, decay = 0, clipnorm = -1, clipvalue = -1), loss      = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics   =  c('categorical_accuracy') )
```

But it is given me an error like this

> Error in modules$keras.optimizers$Adam(lr = lr, beta_1 = beta_2,
> beta_2 = beta_2,  :    attempt to apply non-function

I also used `keras_compile` still getting the same error.
I can change optimizer in compile but the largest learning rate is 0.01, I want to try 0.2.

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>% layer_dense(units = 512, activation = 'relu',  input_shape =  ncol(X_train)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu')%>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.1) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid')%>%
compile( 
  optimizer = 'Adam', 
  loss      = 'binary_crossentropy',
  metrics   =  c('categorical_accuracy') 
)
```

Comment: please provide the code to create your model. The steps you did before compiling.

Comment: Just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is you are using two different libraries `kerasR` and `keras` together. You should use only one of them. First, you are using `keras_model_sequential` function
which is from `keras` and then you try to use `Adam` function which is from `kerasR` library. You find the difference between these two libraries here: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/keras-r-deep-learning#differences

The following code is working for me which is using only `keras` library.

```
library(keras)
model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 512, activation = 'relu',  input_shape =  ncol(X_train)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu')%>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.1) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid')%>%
  compile(optimizer=optimizer_adam(lr = 0.2), loss= 'binary_crossentropy', metrics   =  c('accuracy') )
```

Comment: Is there a way to control imbalance data? Negative/Positive=4.3. In somewhere it says bias_initilizer=log(Negative/Positive) but I cannot assign a number to bias.

Comment: I am not sure how imbalance is related to initialization? is this for the last layer?

Comment: Not exactly, I was looking for a way to deal with imbalanced data problem and a post mentioned initialization.

Comment: if you want to change the bias initialize of the last layer: `layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid', bias_initializer = initializer_constant(log(Negative/Positive)))`

Comment: Can you take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696288/stabilize-neural-network-prediction-for-class-probability