# Stabilize Neural network prediction for class probability

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, prediction

I ve been trying to fit a neural network for binary setting using `library(keras)` and I am interested in class probability (instead of 0/1, probability of the event)

I ve 5.018 times more negative than positive class. I added the code I have been using. I cannot stabilize the predictions. I understand that noise and everything.
***But I need to put some constraints to get close estimates each time.*** I am out of ides. Is there anything else I can use to stabilize predictions?

I cannot share the data therefore here is summary of predictions at train data level and I plotted validations/train.

```
 first run               Second run
 Min.   :0.001843       Min.   :0.0004508 
 1st Qu.:0.012272       1st Qu.:0.0156236 
 Median :0.042264       Median :0.0459510 
 Mean   :0.142551       Mean   :0.1400624  
 3rd Qu.:0.195536       3rd Qu.:0.1937293
 Max.   :0.919892       Max.   :0.9882065
```

validation plot for first run [image: first run] and validation plot for second run[image]

```
l2_model <- 
  keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 512, activation = "relu", input_shape =  ncol(XX_train1),
              kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.001)) %>% 
  layer_batch_normalization()%>%
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu", 
              kernel_regularizer = regularizer_l2(0.001)) %>%
  layer_batch_normalization()%>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid",
              bias_initializer = initializer_constant(log(5.0189)))

l2_model %>% compile(
  optimizer="Adam",
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  metrics =  c('accuracy')
)

summary(l2_model)

l2_history <- l2_model %>% fit(
  x                = as.matrix(XX_train1), 
  y                = YY_train1,
  epochs = 30,
  batch_size = 1000,
  validation_data = list(XX_test, YY_test[,2]),
  verbose = 2,
  callbacks = list(
    callback_early_stopping(patience = 2) )
 #   ,callback_reduce_lr_on_plateau()  )
)


# Predicted Class Probability
yhat_keras_prob_vec  <- predict_proba(object = l2_model, x = as.matrix(XX_train1)) %>%
  as.matrix()

summary(yhat_keras_prob_vec)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the nature of your problem? Does your network need to output a probability for one input event or one for each event? Do you have problem stabilizing very high or very low probabilities or all probabilities?

Comment: One idea would be, on case of differently distributed classes, to customize the loss in such way, that the prediction of the smaller class is weighted 5.018 than one of the bigger class with the idea, that a wrong prediction of a smaller class is 5 times as bad as prediction a bigger class wrong. Maybe that gets you more percents. Also, depending on your case you might prefer CNNs or Rnns, as they perform well with many tasks

Comment: @BahmanRouhani I would say doesn't matter. As much as my predictions don't change every time. Like similarly accuracy 0.85 then 0.87 which I am not interested in accuracy since I wanna use class probabilities to use it somewhere else but as an example. I want to get close to the previous run.

Comment: @MichaelJanz I do not know how they (CNN/RNN) do make a difference in the code. Is there a tutorial page I can use? I feel I need to use l1 and l2 regularizations and maybe instead of bias_initilizer, I should use something else.

Answer (score 0):

So I ve been working on and I started controlling bunch on stuff to get kind of close estimates such as `learning rate` and `decay` part of code is like this  `optimizer=optimizer_adam(lr = 0.0001,decay = 0.001)` then I used all regularizers `kernel_regularizer`, bias_regularizer and activity_regularizer as **l2 regularizer** in each `layer_dense()` and finally output layer, I only used *bias and activity regularizer*.